# I don't want to hard code the file that I want opened ('Besties.txt')

Tags: python, file

I have a browse button where you can select any file, I want to be able to open which ever file I select. But the open() method only takes file names, how should I go about doing this?

```py
#browsePath.set(browsePathEntry.get())  (both variables already declared)

def browseButtonClicked():
    browsePath = filedialog.askdirectory()

def submitClicked():
    with open('Besties.txt', 'w') as file:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the community!

Your question is actually about a very beautiful (and useful) part of programming, because in most cases we want to use programs to do the same job over and over again, not just a disposable one-time use.

Say, if you want a function that prints the sum of 1 plus 1, you can simply put:

```
def one_plus1():
    return 1 + 1
```

and at a later time you want a program that prints the sum of 2 plus 1, or even 3 plus 1, you can write more functions like this:

```
def two_plus1():
    return 2 + 1

def three_plus1():
    return 3 + 1
```

Or, you can use a variable so that you can make it any number you want:

```
def just_plus1(x):
    return x + 1
```

when you need to use it for, say, 10+1, just call it with `just_plus1(10)`.

That's it! That's the spirit!

So back to your question, if you want your function to be able to work for any file, just make the file name a parameter of the function:

```
def submitClicked(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
```

For your example you just need to call `submitClicked('Besties.txt')` to run it. Now you can safely replace the plain text file name in the function call with any name you want, or you may want/need to use a variable (probably related to `browsePath` in your case) to store the string-typed file name text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My guess is OP needs that last full paragraph fleshed out.

Comment: @ScottHunter I guess so. I'm feeling that would require more info from OP about the program the OP's writing...